# How to disable previous dates in ui date picker

Tags: jquery, html, calendar

I have script as below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#sDate , #eDate").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true
      });
  });
```

My html input fields are as follows:

```
<input type="text"  readonly name="scheduleStartDate" id="sDate" />
<input type="text"  readonly name="scheduleEndDate" id="eDate" />
```

when I click on image, I'm getting the ui calender for input fields, Please help me to disable previous dates in the calender so that the user can only select the start date from today's date and onwards. Thank you!

Comment: if you're using the official jQuery Datepicker you might take a look at the official doc `http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate`

Comment: Useful information Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `minDate` attribute to your code like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#sDate , #eDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(2015, 6, 29)
    });
});
</script>
```

Where 2015 is the year, 6 is the month and 29 is the date. The date before 29/06/2015 will be disabled.

Note: Assuming the datepicker you've used is jQuery datepicker.

Comment: I have created new date object without hard coded values, now it's working +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Set `minDate:0` in `datepicker()` function

Comment: In case of such one-liners you could at least provide a link to the official documentation.